# Gnome shell weather extension is not showing correct weather information

Tags: gnome, 11.10, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

I am on Ubuntu 11.10 and I have installed Gnome shell extensions.

For the weather extension the problem is that it is only showing the temperature that it showed when installed for the first time. That means while the current temperature is 25 it is continuing to show it as 32.

I have entered the correct WOEID.

Need your help to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3):

This is what i did:

1. go to http://weather.yahoo.com and enter your location
2. klick on "**RSS**" (on the right side)
3. your location code is shown in the address-bar 
   (eg. weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?p=**GMXX0087**&u=f)
4. copy your code (**GMXX0087** in my case) and open a terminal
5. set location and city with

   gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.weather woeid "'**GMXX00187**'"

   gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.weather city **YOURCITY**
6. logout & login again

Comment: Thanks for the steps. Actually I did all the steps earlier and tried them again now. But for some reason my temp still shows "Haze 34 C" while it is actually Haze 28 C (I logged out and then logged in). The city for which I am trying to the get the temp is "Kolkata, India" WOEID is "INXX0028"

Comment: As soon as I put those commands into terminal (with my details) the extension worked, did not even have to log out. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. Although it's weird the "new" applet does not have the ability to enter your location directly, whereas the "old" one did.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, after I used the 3 letter code additional to my WOEID code it was successful.

Comment: I have only mentioned the six character code of my city. That means I need to add three more letters code to it? Can you please specify more about three letter code and how to get it?

Comment: City: "FRA" (Frankfurt, Germany) WOEID: "GMXX0040" (changed to this after given the correct WOEID; I don't know your city)

Comment: I am trying for city "Kolkata, India", for which the WOEID is "INXX0028".

Answer (score 1):

Alternative:

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/10/my-weather-indicator-adds-geolocation-support/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=twitter&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+d0od+%28OMG%21+Ubuntu%21%29

A new ‘My Weather Indicator’ Adds Geolocation Support

Comment: Thanks for the link but will that work for gnome-shell (Sorry that I didn't mention specifically) ? I think it is meant for Unity.

Answer (score 0):

[http://xoap.weather.com/search/search?where=**Guangzhou**](http://xoap.weather.com/search/search?where=Guangzhou)

That website is where I solved my problem. Change 'Guangzhou' to your city instead, and the id is what you want.

Comment: This does not provide a sufficient answer to the question. Try to add more information, and / or examples.

Answer (score 0):

The above suggestions did not work for me, so I figured out the following steps, which got me the exact weather for my location.  Sorry, I would post more links but the forum does not allow me to post more than 2 links.

1. Go to the [Yahoo weather](http://weather.yahoo.com/) page.
2. Then, search for your city.  In the URL, you will see a unique numerical ID for your location.  For example, Kansas City's ID is `2430683`.
3. Copy that numerical ID and put it at the end of this link: `http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=`. This is the link for the RSS feed.  For example, for Kansas City the RSS link would be `http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2430683`
4. Towards the bottom of the RSS feed page, you will see a hyperlink that reads "Full Forecast at Yahoo! Weather".  Click that link.  It will open the Yahoo weather page for your location again, however the URL will be different.  The URL now should contain the WOEID that has both letters and numbers.  For example, the Kansas City WOEID is `USMO0460`.

5) To update your WOEID, you can follow the terminal instructions in the first answer above and type in your terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.weather woeid "'GMXX00187'"
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.weather city YOURCITY
```

Then log out and log in.

Alternatively: You can click the weather app button and click on the upper right settings button. Then type in the WOEID and Override Location Label.

Comment: "The above suggestions" is really relative, since answers are always sorted by their voted score. So the order might change in the future.

Comment: I've changed your answer make easier to read. You can always [change it back](http://askubuntu.com/posts/381842/edit) if you don't approve.